# Wait for nested subscribe in angular before continuing with main subscribe (rxJs)

Tags: angular, rxjs, substring

I ran into a problematic one, I need to execute all nested methods (which include subscirbe) and only then set isLoading = false, but the isLoading flag sets to false before all the nested logic has been executed.

Can you tell me if you have any ideas?
I tried to write the code schematically without going into details

```
getData() {
 isLoading = true;
 this.someSevice.getSomeData().subscribe(response => {
   ...
   getUserData(response);
   isLoading = false;
 },
  error => {
    isLoading = false;
    this.errors = error;
 });
}

getUserData(data: any) {
  ...
  this.someSevice.getUserData().subscribe(response => {
    ...
    getMetadata(response);
  });
}

getMetadata(data: any) { 
  ...
  this.someSevice.getMetadata().subscribe(response => {
    ...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you can do is using pipe to execute your requests sequentially with the `mergeMap` operator. This is a common pattern if you have sequential requests where each request requires the response of the prior one. `mergeMap` requires at least one parameter that must be a function that returns an `Observable` (or alternatively a `Promise`). So I also modified `getUserData` and `getMetadata` for that reason.

```
getData() {
  isLoading = true;
  this.someSevice.getSomeData().pipe(
    mergeMap(getUserData),
    mergeMap(getMetadata),
  )
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      isLoading = false;
    },
    error => {
      isLoading = false;
      this.errors = error;
    },
  );
}

getUserData(data: any) {
  ...
  return this.someSevice.getUserData();
}

getMetadata(data: any) { 
  ...
  return this.someSevice.getMetadata();
}
```

Comment: This is the solution. Never do nested subscribes, rxjs provides all you need in order to prevent that anti pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid nested subscribes by utilizing "[Higher Order Mapping Operators](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)" (`mergeMap`, `concatMap`, `switchMap`, `exhaustMap`).  These special operators will subscribe to an inner observable for you (*and also manage unsubscribing*) and propagate the emissions from it.

In your case, let's use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap):

```js
  private getData() {
    this.isLoading = true;

    this.service.getSomeData().pipe(
      switchMap(data => this.service.getUserData(data.userId)),
      switchMap(user => this.service.getMetaData(user.id)),
      tap(() => this.isLoading = false)  // <--- at this point, all calls are done
    );
  }
```

The above code defines a stream that starts with calling `getSomeData()`; the first `switchMap` receives the value emitted by `getSomeData()` and maps it to a new observable, `getUserData()`, which `switchMap` will internally subscribe to and pass the output to the next `switchMap`, which in turn does the same thing.

By the time the `tap` operator is hit, all responses from all 3 prior calls have been received.

---

If we wanted to build up a data response that relies on responses from the prior calls, we'd need a way to access that data from those prior calls.

This can be achieved by adding a `.pipe()` inside the `switchMap`, essentially nesting them like this:

```js
private getData(): Observable<VmData> {
    this.isLoading = true;

    return this.service.getSomeData().pipe(
        switchMap(session => this.service.getUserData(session.userId).pipe(
            switchMap(user => this.service.getMetaData(user.id).pipe(
                // by nesting, map has access to prior responses
                map(userMeta => this.buildVmData(session, user, userMeta))             ))
        )),
        tap(() => this.isLoading = false)
    );
}
```

Check out this fully working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66588210?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) example.  I'm sure you can modify it to fit your needs :-)