# set property of an observable object with an api call

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subscribe

I have a service function like the one below.

```
getByIdWithCategory(id: number): Observable<Product> {

    const category = new Category();
    category.name = 'sample category';

    return this.httpClient.get<Product>(this.baseUrl + `/${id}`)
      .pipe(map(product => ({...product, category})));
  }
```

I get the value returned from here with the async pipe in the template file. But I need to get the category from api. I need to subscribe for this. But then I can't unsubscribe. What is the best practice for this?

The function below does exactly what I want. But I couldn't find a way to unsubscribe from the api call I get the category from.

```
  getByIdWithCategory(id: number): Observable<Product> {

    return this.httpClient.get<Product>(this.baseUrl + `/${id}`)
      .pipe(
        tap(product => {
          this.categoryService.getById(product.id)
            .subscribe(category => {
              product.category = category;
            });
        })
      );
  }
```

Here's how in my product class.

```
export class Product {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  description: string;
  categoryId: number;
  image: string;

  category: Category;
}
```

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66588210/wait-for-nested-subscribe-in-angular-before-continuing-with-main-subscribe-rxjs/66588814

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid nested subscriptions. And subscribing inside the `tap` operator looks particularly inelegant. Instead you could use `switchMap` to map from one observable to another. And pipe `map` to the inner observable and return the whole object with the `category` property.

Try the following

```js
getByIdWithCategory(id: number): Observable<Product> {
  return this.httpClient.get<Product>(this.baseUrl + `/${id}`).pipe(
    switchMap((product: Product) => {
      this.categoryService.getById(product.id).pipe(
        map((category: Category) => ({
          ...product,
          category: category
        }))
      )
    })
  );
}
```