# RxJs - Dynamically add synchronous calls that depend on eachother to a fork join without nesting

Tags: angular, dictionary, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I'm trying to avoid nesting some synchronous calls that depend on each other. I also want to do a subscribe at the end result when all are finished, like a forkjoin.

I have found how to do this on stackoverflow ([Wait for nested subscribe in angular before continuing with main subscribe (rxJs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66588210/wait-for-nested-subscribe-in-angular-before-continuing-with-main-subscribe-rxjs)), but not how to do it **Dynamically**.

Currently I'm using a callback, but this doesn't work with a subscribe when all finished / forkjoin behavior:

```
public keys = ['stateId', 'countyId'];


function populate(index, params = null) {


let route = this.baseRoute + this.keys[index];

this.apiCall(route, params).subscribe(response => {

if (index + 1 < keys.length) {
this.populate(index + 1, this.getParamsFromResponse(response));

}
```

Here's the answer from the above referenced stackoverflow link:

> ```
>  getData() {
>   isLoading = true;
>   this.someSevice.getSomeData().pipe(
>     mergeMap(getUserData),
>     mergeMap(getMetadata),
>   )
>   .subscribe(
>     response => {
>       isLoading = false;
>     },
>     error => {
>       isLoading = false;
>       this.errors = error;
>     },
>   );
> }
> ```

Using the answer in the above referenced stackoverflow link, I don't know how to

A - plug in the mergeMaps dynamically via loop instead of hardcoding them in

B - pass the appropriate arguments to the mergeMaps (route and params)

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you want to loop over (what values? what array? what iterable?) instead of hard-coding? MergeMap gets passed the emissions of the source observable, but if `route` and `params` are in scope, you can just use them.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you mean?
If you can have the observable in an array you could use `reduce` operator to go through them in sequential order.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    const listOfString = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'];
    listOfString
      .slice(1, listOfString.length) // has to exclude the first item as we already defined it below
      .reduce(
        (a, b) => a.pipe(mergeMap((aResult) => this.getData(b, aResult))),
        this.getData(listOfString[0], null) //first call
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

  getData(input: string, params: string): Observable<string> {
    const result = `${input} ${params ? params : ''}`;
    console.log(result);
    return of(result);
  }
```

Comment: It could be simplified to the `pipe(...listOfObservables.map(mergeMap))` where pipe comes from `import {pipe} from 'rxjs'`.

Comment: we can use map if each observable doesn't depend on the previous one, but if they depend on each other then you need to use reduce

Comment: Sorry, what about this `pipe(...createFns.map(fn => mergeMap(previousResponse => fn(previousResponse)))`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Two things: As is, this throws an error for me. Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<number>'. 

Also, I don't have an array of observables, just an array of strings. I'm not sure how to translate the string array into an observable array because the observable needs to be passed an argument based on the response from the pervious observable.

Comment: And it could be again simplified like this: `pipe(...createFns.map(mergeMap))` where the `createFns = [() => firstTask(), resultOfFirst => secondTask(resultOfFirst), /* and so on */]`

Comment: reduce is an array operator that you will send in a function like this
(a,b)=> {some logic to combine them together}. which a is the first item of the array and b is the second one. you can use reduce with an array of string items as. I think reduce is what you are looking for. give it a try and see if it works

Comment: this is an example with string array
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-rqi2xj

Answer (score 1):

Solution without reduce:

```js
const {pipe, of} = rxjs;
const {mergeMap, tap} = rxjs.operators;

of({
  initValue: 1,
  sequence: [
    value => of(value + 2),
    value => of(value * 2),
    value => of(`result is: ${value}`),
  ],
})
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(({ initValue, sequence }) =>
      of(initValue).pipe(
        ...sequence.map(stepFn => mergeMap(stepFn))
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@^7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly are the function you have in your example doing but if `getParamsFromResponse()` returns an Observable you could use something along these lines:

```
this.apiCall(route, params)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(response => 
      forkJoin(keys.map(key => this.populate(index + 1, this.getParamsFromResponse(response))))
    )
  )
  .subscribe(allResponses => /* one large array after all Observables completed */)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. the this.getParamsFromResponse(response) is just taking the response from the last observable and extracting the relevant data, in the form of an object. So no, it is not an Observable.